# Class 'Pimple\Container' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, pimple

I am trying to install Pimple in my project following https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple readme file.

Error message I receive is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Pimple\Container' not found in E:\www\public\index.php on line 9
```

My composer.json file is:

```
{
  ...
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "5.1.*"
  },
  "require": {
    "pimple/pimple": "~3.0"
  }
}
```

When I do:

```
composer update
```

or

```
composer install
```

the message is: *Nothing to install or update*

In vendor/bin I can see only phpunit files. I can see however pimple in composer.lock

My PHP index.php file:

```
<?php

    use Pimple\Container;

    $co = new Container();

?>
```

Could you please help me make it work?

Comment: Have you ran `composer dump-autoload` or just `composer dump`? Are you including the `vendor/autoload.php` file in your project?

Comment: I didn't include autoload.php. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

vendor/autoload.php was not included and this caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete Vendor content, and install dev again througth composer.

Comment: You should provide short answer as a comment instead of an answer.